# Android TableLayout does not scroll vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

Thanks in advance for any help. I am very new to Android.

Here's my problem. I am using a TableLayout to display editable fields. There are about twenty rows to display.

The rows overflow the screen on smaller devices. I need the View to allow the user to scroll up and down. What am I missing?

Tried wrapping the TableLayout in a ScrollView, didn't work.

Comment: Putting it in a ScrollView should work. Post the layout that you tried.

Comment: go to link, you can see 'Android Table Scroll with Fixed Header and Column' :
Click [here](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html "Android Table Scroll with Fixed Header and Column")!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

put your `TableLayout` inside `ScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </TableRow>



        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where would this go?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

but how about using a `listView` instead?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wouldn't have thought of that. Is it normal in Android to have so much nesting? (A Table Layout wrapped by a Scroll View and then wrapped by a Linear Layout)? My project does not have the Linear Layout wrapper. It seems to be working fine. Should I have it?

Comment: You're right, it is not necessary to use the `LinearLayout`. I used it simply because in `Eclipse`, on creating a new project, the XML file contains that default layout, and from there I started to try to create the layout you needed. How did you create your xml? If you update your question with the code, maybe I can help you...